# Safari jQuery syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, jquery-selectors

I get the following error in safari (7.0.3).  Chrome and FF have no complaints and work just fine.

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #filters input:not([name^="radio-"]`

From this line of code:

`jQuery('#filters input:not([name^="radio-"]').change(function(e) {
    triggerIsotopeUpdate();
});`

I have not been able to find solutions on SO that apply to my situation.  Has anyone encountered this issue before?  I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket (before `.change()`):

```
jQuery('#filters input:not([name^="radio-"])').change(function(e) {
                                           ^
    triggerIsotopeUpdate();
});
```

Comment: I looked over the syntax before posting. Sorry, I can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: @Thomas it happens. I didn't notice it at first either :p

Comment: Well thanks @billyonecan , I appreciated the quick and accurate response!